# OpenSearch/ElasticSearch Equivalent to SQL "CREATE INDEX" to sort while inserting documents

Tags: sql, sorting, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

In SQL Databases, can we use the statement "CREATE INDEX" to keep the table sorted by a field after each insert and improve read performance? Can we do the same in OpenSearch/ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible in both Elasticsearch and Opensearch using a feature called [index sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html), where you define the sorting criteria in the index settings and then all the data is indexed in a sorted manner.

The sorting supposedly slows down a little bit the indexing throughput, but the idea is that sorting at search time will be much faster.